# Reverse for not found

Tags: python, django

I have some question about redirect. When i am using `mapviews.index` there are no errors but when i am using `mpviews.index`

```
Reverse for 'mythicPlus.views.index' not found. 'mythicPlus.views.index' is not a valid view function or pattern name
```

What should i do to fix this problem?

*shopping_cart/views.py*

```py
from mythicPlus import views as mpviews
from mainPage import views as mapviews

return redirect(reverse(mpviews.index))
```

mythicPlus/urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name = 'mythicPlus_list'),
```

*mythicPlus/views.py*

```
def index(request):
    boost_keys_list = mythicPlusOrders.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list': boost_keys_list}
    return render(request, "mythicPlus/posts.html", context)
```

*mainPage/views.py*

```py
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mainPage/homePage.html')
```

Comment: Can you give details of what 'mythicPlus_list' is? There is no variable, module etc. of that name. Is it the type of `mpviews.index`?

Comment: You haven't shown us where `mythicPlus.views.index` is being used as a view name.  Where is that happening?  In another view, or a template, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reverse` uses the viewname from the url so in `path('my-url/', views.MyView.as_view(), name="my-view")` the viewname is my-view

You need to provide that in your `reverse`.  Or you could just do 
`redirect(mpviews.index)`

Comment: sry my bad i mean my error Reverse for 'mythicPlus.views.index' not found. 'mythicPlus.views.index' is not a valid view function or pattern name. 
Ps: fixed it in description